# how to open pdf files in loop using vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, subscript

i got error out of range on lbound and uboud. please help. this are my codes.
Its working on other macro i made.
Error starts at ubound and lbound. when i run it, its resulting to subscript error. I just copy at my past codes.

```
Option Explicit
Public pdfpath, excelpath As String
Public pdfname, fname, issuename, excelname As String
Public wb As Workbook
Public ws, wspdf As Worksheet
Public STRinvoice, STRamnt, STRissue, STRcus As String
Public SAPinvoice, SAPamnt, SAPissue, SAPcus As String
Public i, ctr As Long
Public rfile() As Variant

Sub DO_ALL()

pdfpath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Wiley Checker\PDF IN\"
excelpath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Wiley Checker\EXCEL IN\"
pdfname = Dir(pdfpath & "*.pdf*")
ctr = 1


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Checker")
Set wspdf = wb.Sheets("PDF")


Do Until pdfname = ""
    If InStr(pdfname, "pdf") > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve rfile(1 To ctr)
        rfile(ctr) = pdfname
        ctr = ctr + 1
    End If
pdfname = Dir
Loop

For i = LBound(rfile) To UBound(rfile)

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink pdfpath & rfile(i)
'continous codes.....
Next i

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

i just want to loop opening pdf files.

Comment: FYI: When declaring multiples variables on the same line, you need to give the type of each variable explicitly or the type will be applied only to the last one, the others being on type Variant.

Comment: Your error means that `rfile` is either no array or empty. Check the content of `rfile` when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the Array rfile is not initialized. Please check you have files in pdfpath and at least one file pass InStr(pdfname, "pdf") check.

To be safe, use:

```
If ctr > 1 Then
    For i = LBound(rfile) To UBound(rfile)

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink pdfpath & rfile(i)
    'continous codes.....
    Next i
End If
```